# How can one determine the continuity type of a sequence of functions using Geometry?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In my lecture note, there was something about determining the continuity type (pointwise continuity, uniform continuity) by just plotting the function. Can someone explain this idea?

**Edit:** The example was the sequence $(f_n(x))_n$, where for each $n$, $f_n$ a real function given by $f_n(x):= \frac{nsin(nx)}{x^2+n^2}$.

Comment: 1. Draw the function without lifting the pen. 2. Complete 1 within a finite time.

Answer (score 0):

All continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous, so determining the continuity type (for continuous real functions on real numbers) is only relevant to functions defined on an open interval. The idea is to check the function near the open endpoint(s) of the interval: can its height be kept within a small interval of fixed length (between two rulers a fixed distance apart, say) without having to continually narrow the horizontal interval over which the function is being checked? If so, it is uniformly continuous. Otherwise, it might behave, for instance, like $f(x) = \frac 1x$ near $x=0$. (The given example - I'm assuming $n$ is a positive integer - is uniformly continuous over the real number line, because you don't have to keep narrowing the horizontal interval to keep the function within a vertical interval of fixed length).

For a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$, equicontinuity can be 'checked' visually by drawing $f_n(x)$ for multiple values of $n$. An equicontinuous sequence of functions is one in which you don't have to keep narrowing the horizontal interval over which you are checking in order to keep the height of *each function* in the sequence within a vertical interval (the position of which can change with the function) of fixed length.

Comment: There is also some concern about *equicontinuity* when dealing with sequences (which apparently the OP has in their problem).

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why the $n$. I'll cover that.